# Angularjs Unit Tests not modeling data from SELECT node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to angularjs and trying to Unit Test my directive. I actually tested it in a fully-working browser session first because it seemed easier, but I wanted to get into unit testing because it's best practice.

In my browser session, my directive functions exactly as I expect it to. It creates a `<select>` tag that uses `ng-model` to bind to a property on the `$rootScope`.

However, when I test with Karma using Jasmine syntax (as the Angular docs recommend), I'm not able to get the model update on the `$rootScope` when I change the value of the `<select>` element.

Here's my Jasmine code. It's a snippet, but I assure you that the variables not explicitly defined in the below code are correctly defined using `$inject()`. I've tested them out to make sure they weren't screwing up:

```
var el = $compile("<my-directive my-model='myModel'></my-directive>")($scope);
//the 'my-model' value, 'myModel', gets assigned during the link phase to:
//$scope.$root.fields[myModel]
var $el = angular.element(el);
$el.find('select').val('someVal');
$rootScope.$digest();
expect($scope.$root.fields[myModel]).toEqual("someVal");
```

The error that I get is:

```
Expected '' to equal 'someVal'
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the `$digest()` phase? Or how `ng-model` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose I'll answer my own question, as I discovered it while waiting for an answer here.

The problem was that I needed to call `.change()`, or otherwise trigger the `change` event on the select element.

So I learned something important today! Angular's `ng-model` directive will only pickup changes after an event has been fired. Good to learn in testing than in debugging, so I guess unit testing works!